# why is my If_Else code always one condition only printed while there are more true conditions in the else_if conditions

Tags: if-statement

in if else statement, my code only prints one condition and the rest are left undone. What is the compiler executes  if two or more conditions consecutively are true

Answer (score 0):

I think so that you are confused with if else_if and else.
If is like the primary statement which will be first checked to be true and if it's then the code is executed.Else_if is like secondary statement which will be checked (if mentioned) only if the if statement is false. Else is the code to be executed if neither if nor else_if statement is True. I think you are trying to run both if and else if statement in the program keep in mind that if "if" statement is true then it will not execute the else_if and else statement and will pass after the execution of if block is done.